# Registering GPX (or XML) file to open in iOS app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, ios5

I am having trouble opening GPX files in my iOS app. I registered the extension and some files open correctly, that is when I tap on a link to GPX file in Safari, it shows a prompt asking me which application I want to use to open the file. Then I select my application and the file is processed as expected. With some websites in Safari and with all files from email attachments, the prompt and app selection is not displayed and the browser/email app shows contents of the file as text.

I suspect this is problem with the info.plist settings or possibly with the Safari and email apps. If you open XML or GPX files in your ios apps correctly, would you post your CFBundleDocumentTypes and UTExportedTypeDeclarations settings from info.plist?

Any thoughts are welcome. Here is the appropriate section from my info.plist. I tried to add and remove some optional tags, this is the latest, but not most complete.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Icon.png</string>
            <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>GPS eXchange Format</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>org.elsners.Indicium.gpx</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.xml</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>GPS eXchange Format</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>org.elsners.Indicium.gpx</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>GPX</string>
                <string>gpx</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Mirek, did you ever solve this problem? Mind posting a solution for those still looking?

Comment: No, I did not find a solution, sorry. With email attachments, it shows the correct icon, but when I tap it, it opens as a text file.

Comment: The latest Stanford class if exactly about this subject! They might have posted the sample code

Answer (score 1):

When working with HTTP content (which is the case of Safari and Mail app), you must not forget to handle its content type. The [Uniform Type Identifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html) (UTI) for handle content type is `public.mime-type` and let's say that the content type header of a server response is set to *application/gpx*, so in your *plist* you must add to the `UTTypeTagSpecification` section:

```
<dict>
  <key>public.filename-extension</key>
   <array>
     <string>GPX</string>
     <string>gpx</string>
   </array>
   <key>public.mime-type</key>
   <string>application/gpx</string>
</dict>
```

**Note**: I've seen *application/gpx* and *application/gpx+xml* as content type for GPX data around web and I don't know if there's a standard mime type so it's better to use both.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{

    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {

        //  xdxf file type handling

        if ([[url pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"xdxf"]) {

            NSLog(@"URL:%@", [url absoluteString]);

        }

    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: HI Jaffer, thanks for your comment. I have similar code in my app. The code sample you provided would process the file, but the original problem is that the app is not launched when user activates GPX file in another app.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following part must be removed:

```
<key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
<array>
    <string>public.xml</string>
</array>
```

I reproduced the issue with it, and fixed by removal.

Apparently mail app thinks that it can handle XML-conforming types better than other apps, and intercepts handling.

I would also recommend including changes from [answer posted by Wallace Campos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484220/registering-gpx-or-xml-file-to-open-in-ios-app/34662032#34662032).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. My app wasn't being shown in the list of apps to open the XML attachment from the mail app. I used this code in info.plist and it worked for me:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>XML File</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
          <string>public.XML</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
          <string>Sandbox-icon.png</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
```

Refer: http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/how-to-register-file-types-supported-by-an-ios-app.html